# Are remote branches locally available?

Tags: git, git-branch

Quite new with Git here. What does remote branches mean? Are they locally available (assuming there is no Internet)?

For examples, here are all my branches, I would like to know whether my local machine has all it needs to get the info from my `gh-pages` branch?

```
$git branch -a

* main
  remotes/origin/gh-pages
  remotes/origin/main
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, when you clone a repository, you get a whole copy of the remote repository, with all branches. The `remote` branches in your local repository are thus also often called `remote-tracking` branches. They are locally stored in your repository, but track the branches in the remote repository (with operations like `git fetch`).

Edit: As iBug has mentioned in their answer, there are some flags for the `clone` command, which would not create an exact copy of the remote repository, but only download parts of it, so if you used such flags, you need to check).

Answer (score 4):

There are 3 types of branches of which you need to be aware most of the time in Git.  They are:

- Local branches.  This includes the `gh-pages` branch.  These branches are saved locally, and in them you do your actual work.
- Remote tracking branches.  This includes `remotes/origin/gh-pages`.  These are also local branches, but they mainly exist to serve as proxies for the true remote branches which exist on the Git repository (e.g. Bitbucket and GitHub).  Whenever you do a `git fetch`, you update these (local) remote tracking branches
- Remote branches.  This includes the `gh-pages` branch as it exists on the actual remote Git server.  When you do a `git push` to the branch, or complete a pull request having this branch as the destination, you update this true remote branch.

Now coming to your question:

> I would like to know whether my local machine has all it needs to get the info from my gh-pages branch?

Typically, you can just type `git status` from the `gh-pages` branch.  The response you get will tell you how many commits ahead/behind you are from the remote tracking branch.  The key word in the previous sentence was "tracking," because your local `git status` command will *not* compare your local `gh-pages` against what is on the remote.  Rather, it will compare against the *local* remote tracking branch.  So, to get the most accurate status report, you should do these steps:

```
# from gh-pages
git fetch
gig status
```

The output you see from the above will tell really where your local branch stands regards any new work which might have come into the remote branch.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they are locally available.

They are local copies of what was on the remote server the last time you ran `git fetch` or `git pull`.

---

- If you want to update that remote view : run `git fetch`.
  Unlike `git pull`, `git fetch` will only update these remote branches, and will not try to update your own local branches.
- If for some reason you want to see what branches exist on the remote server without downloading their content : use `git ls-remote`
- In any case, even if your local view of the remote is outdated, `git push` will make sure both views are consistent before updating anything

Comment: strong emphasis on _since the last time you ran a `fetch` or `pull`_. More than once I found myself explaining colleagues that no, they don't have that particular remote branch locally. Also, in the most basic example where you have only one remote, and that is called `origin`, and you don't change names to the branches when pulling, then you should be able to find both `yourBranch` and `origin/yourBranch` in the repository. One is your local copy, the other represent the most up-to-date info you retrieve from the remote on that branch.

Answer (score 1):

Assume you didn't add `--depth` during `git clone`, `git pull` or similar commands, then **yes, your local repository has everything for the remote branches**.

To check them out, all you need to do is `git checkout -b new-branch origin/main`. You can also see what commits they're pointing at with `git log origin/main` as well.